# Raspberry Pi blinking LED every time button is on

Tags: python, switch-statement, gpio, led, pi

I have a raspberry pi attached to toggle switches and LEDs. Each switch turns on a LED and the third switch activates it's corresponding LED as well as making another blink for 20 seconds. Currently the python script will let you switch the buttons off and on as much as you want but that last while argument only runs the first time. How can I change this to blink that third LED every time GPIO 25 has been switched on?

```
t_end = time.time() + 20
while(1):

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
    print ("Phase 1 Initiated")
    sounda.play()

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(24, GPIO.FALLING)
    print ("Phase 2 Initiated")
    soundb.play()

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(25, GPIO.FALLING)
    print ("Phase 3 Initiated")
    soundc.play()
    while time.time() < t_end:
        GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH) 
        sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW) 
        sleep(.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `t_end` to be equal to `time.time() + 20` before your outer while loop, and never updating it after that, so that once 20 seconds has passed and `time.time()` becomes equal to and then greater than `t_end`, the code in your inner `while time.time() < t_end` while loop will never be executed again.

Because the two `sleep(.5)` statements in this code

```
while time.time() < t_end:
    GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH) 
    sleep(.5)
    GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW) 
    sleep(.5)
```

mean that each blink cycle is taking one second due to having the LED on for a half second and off for a half second, why not just replace `while time.time() < t_end:` with `for i in range(20):` and then you get your 20 seconds of blinking without needing to deal with any extra time variable.

Comment: This worked a lot better, thank you. I tied it to a threaded function and now the camera and led work without the complication of time.time